# Regex python remove colons and underscores

Tags: python, regex

I have a method that cleans tweets that I got from online, however I want to modify it so it will keep colons and underscores. I read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for regex in python and it seems the re.sub method is first finding the pattern, then replacing it with blank spaces, in the "tweet" variable. I still do not quite understand the first part where it specifies the patterns to find I understand some basics like ^ is finding if something starts with something, I tried taking out the last part `(\w+:\/\/\S+)` entirely thinking that was where the colon was coming from, but it is still removing colons. Can someone explain what each 3 parts of the pattern finding part does?

```
' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", tweet).split())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ^ character has two meanings in regexps. It can be the beginning of the string or it can mean "not" if in between brackets ([]). In this case, it means not, which means all characters not specifically mentioned in that expression is removed. To have it *not* remove colon (:) you should add that to the middle (not) group:

```
' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t:])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", tweet).split())
```

To further explain; the first group removes @-references to others, the second group removes all non-alphanumerics except space and tab (and now colon) and the last group remove internet addresses and the like (e.g. staring at "http://" or "file://" or similar).

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't know ^ had two meanings